# Can HAProxy 1.6 forward to urls?

Tags: haproxy

Can I define backend servers like:

`Server server1 abc.def.com:8080/xyz check port 8080`

Instead of `ip:port` for server?

Applying such config I receive `503 Service Unavailable` error.

Any idea on the right config if any?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No because HAProxy has not level 7 forwarding. It stands to you to redirect all traffic to `abc.def.com:8080` and then create :

- a server on that machine listening on port `8080`
- a service responding on `/xyz` request path

Comment: Or you can connect to proxy.frontend.ip:port/xyz which will redirect you to abc.def.com/xyz

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried using redir for redirecting to URL with IP:port as backend. But was looking for an elegant / better way to do it w.r.t. URLs.